# PHP curl_setopt error with IPRESOLVE

Tags: php, android, mysql, curl

I am trying to send information from MySQL database to Android users using PHP. My code works very well when I use my localhost and I have notification to my app, but when I am using the online free hosting (000webhost), I get the following error:

> Warning: curl_setopt() [function.curl-setopt]: Invalid curl configuration option in /home/a2275966/public_html/send_notification.php on line 24
>   line 24 contains this code:

```
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE,CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
```

I tried to use `CURL_IPRESOLVE_V6` or `CURL_IPRESOLVE_WHATEVER` but didn't work.
Is this a limitation in the hosting website, or is there something missing in my code? The curl version is `7.15.5` and the PHP version is `5.2.17` on the free host.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
require "init.php";
$message = $_POST['message'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$path_to_fcm='https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$server_key="AIzaSyBIUnk81EnIIrrlM1FfSxVCHPGqptuf3FQ";
$sql="select fcm_token from fcm_info";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
$key=$row[0];
$headers= array(
'Authorization:key=' .$server_key,
'Content-Type:application/json'
);
$fields = array('to'=>$key,
'notification'=>array('title'=>$title,'body'=>$message));
$payload=json_encode($fields);
$curl_session=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_URL,$path_to_fcm);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_POST,true);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$headers);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_IPRESOLVE,CURL_IPRESOLVE_V4);
curl_setopt($curl_session,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$payload);

$results=curl_exec($curl_session);
if($results)
    echo "donne";
else
    echo "nnnooo";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: what curl library is your php using? `ipresolve` was added in curl 7.10.8

Comment: In addition to what @MarcB mentioned, you also need PHP 5.3+

Comment: @MarcB curl 7.15.5

Comment: Current PHP is PHP version: 5.2.17 @apokryfos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cURL option was added in PHP version 5.3+ and cURL version 7.10.8, 
since you are using a cURL version which supports it you can either:

1) Upgrade your PHP version (recommended since 5.2 has some issues which make your site vulnerable to exploits)

2) Use the actual numeric values of those constants. Those can be found in the cURL source at https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/include/curl/curl.h you should ideally find the equivalent file for your cURL version but I doubt constants would get different numbers per version.

`IPRESOLVE` seems to be value 113 and IPRESOLVE_V4 is 1 so you'd do something like:

```
curl_setopt($curl_session,113,1);
```